# Return IIS Windows Authentication Provider in PowerShell for Desired State Configuration script

Tags: powershell, iis-7.5, dsc

I am writing some logic for DSC to check if Negotiate:Kerberos is in the provider list for Windows Authentication under one of our Websites. I've written the logic to check for Windows Authentication and confirm that's turned on:

```
Script ActiveSyncAuthentication
            {
                SetScript = {
                     Set-WebConfiguration system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication -PSPath IIS:\ -Location 'Default Web Site/MySite' -Value @{enabled="True"}
                }
                TestScript = {
                     return ((Get-WebConfigurationProperty //system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication -PSPath IIS:\ -Location 'Default Web Site/MySite' -Name Enabled) -eq "True")  
                }
                GetScript = { }    
            }
```

I know that I can add to the list of providers with the below:

```
Add-WebConfiguration -Filter system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication/providers -PSPath IIS:\ -Location 'Default Web Site/MySite' -Value Negotiate:Kerberos
```

However, I'm struggling with returning this using Get-WebConfiguration or Get-WebConfigurationProperty.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this :

```
        $WinAuthen = Get-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication -PSPath $PSPath -Name enabled | Select Name,Value
    $WinProviders = Get-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication -PSPath $PSPath -Name Providers
    $WinProviders = $WinProviders.Collection | Select Value
```

Comment: If you do it this way, it'll copy windows auth providers for the site that were inherited, which is  probably not the desired behavior.